# How to use Django URLs in React JSX

Tags: django, url, reactjs, django-urls

I have an existing Django project. I want to use ReactJS within this as React makes handling states really really easy. The issue I am facing is how to re-use the URL templates that are already defined in Django?

Example: Home/urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[
    url(r'plot/api/(?P<plot_id>[0-9]+)?$', views.LivePlot.as_view(), name='livePlot'),
]
```

If i use just Django i can refer to the above url by `{% url 'Home:livePlot' plot_id %}` where plot_id is a parameter passed by the server.

i am unable to leverage the same technique when using React. Any suggestions? I have access to the plot_id within my React code.

React example:

```
render: function() {
   return(<div className="plot"><a href=''></a></div>);
}
```

Ideally in the above example i would like to have a method to place  `{% url 'Home:livePlot' plot_id %}` or something similar within the href attribute of anchor tag, so that the link points to example.com/plot/{plot_id}.

Right now the workaround i was using involved building the url myself. So if i place this react component in example.com/sub/sub2 i would build the url as `'../../plot' + plot_id`. This approach fails miserably when i place the same react component in multiple pages like example.com/sub and example.com/sub/sub2 which is exactly the use-case i have.

Comment: Have you solve this problem and how?

Comment: Not really. Havnt been able to find a good solution for it. For now, i am passing another parameter rootURL, which has the values [, '..', '../..'] and so on. Thereafter this rootURL is appended to all urls in React DOMs. From my template i know whether the path is .. or ../.. and so on.

Comment: Adding a link to @Goran's question, which has a viable answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232541/react-jsx-and-django-reverse-url.