# React JSX and Django reverse URL

Tags: django, django-models, reactjs

I'm trying to build some menu using React and need some Django reverse urls in this menu. Is it possible to get django url tag inside JSX? How can this be used?

```
render: function() {
    return <div>
        <ul className={"myClassName"}>

            <li><a href="{% url 'my_revese_url' %}">Menu item</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a script tag in your page to inject the values from Django into an array.

```
<script>
  var menuItems = [
    {title: 'Menu Item', url: '{% url "my_reverse_url" %}'},
    {title: 'Another Item', url: '{% url "another_reverse_url" %}'},
  ];
</script>
```

You could then pass the array into the menu through a property.

```
<MyMenu items={menuItems}></MyMenu>
```

Then loop over it to create the list items in your `render` method.

```
render: function(){ 
  var createItem = function(itemText) {
    return <li>{itemText}</li>;
  };
  return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
}
```

This will keep your component decoupled and reusable because the logic for creating the data and the logic for displaying the list items is kept separate.

Comment: Thanks @Soviut and then in render just `<a href={this.props.items[0].url}>{this.props.items[0].title}</a>` or what?

Comment: Yes, or you could "loop" to create the items using a `map()` function. I've updated my answer to show the mapping method.